# Calculate the sum of the following infinite sequence: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, telescopic-series

How to calculate the sum of the following infinite sequence?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)} = ?$$

Comment: See also: [Sum of the series $\sum^{∞}_{n = 1} \frac{1}{(2n + 1)(2n - 1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4102819) and [Prove $\frac{1}{1 \cdot 3} + \frac{1}{3 \cdot 5} + \frac{1}{5 \cdot 7} + \cdots$ converges to $\frac 1 2 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/177373).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

There exist real numbers $A$ and $B$ such that

$$\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)} = \frac{A}{2n-1} + \frac{B}{2n+1}$$

> $\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)} = \frac{0.5}{2n-1} - \frac{0.5}{2n+1}$

See if anything cancels nicely.

> If you are still having trouble, search for the phrase "*telescoping series*" for more information on how to continue.